# Как отправить массив $_SESSION html в бд MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть массив $_SESSION["shopping_cart"], он содержит массивы, как бы массив массивов.
Нужно взорвать этот на несколько массивов, и при нажатии кнопки нужно отправить их в таблицу MySQl.

[image: Массив $_SESSION["shopping_cart"]]

```
if(isset($_POST["send_data"]))  
{  
   $item_array = $_SESSION["shopping_cart"]; 
    

     function opt($array,$connect)
     {
        if(is_array($array))
          {
               foreach($array as $row => $value)
               {
                    $item_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$value[0]);
                    $item_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$value[1]);
                    $item_qty = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$value[2]);

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `dlya_povara` (`Название блюда`, `Цена`, `Количество блюд`, ) VALUES ('$item_name','$item_price','$item_qty')";
               }          
               if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
               {  
                   echo '<script>alert("Регистрация прошла")</script>';  
               } 
               else
               {
                     echo '<script>alert("Регистрация не прошла")</script>';
               }
               
          }
     }
     opt($item_array,$connect);
}
```

Comment: Не надо взрывать массивы. В цикле составляйте запрос, после его выполняйте. В чём проблема, конкретизируйте?

Comment: То есть с этим кодом все в порядке?

Comment: этот код работает? делает что ожидается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё-таки, не удержался от ответа.

1. Не надо заниматься транслитерацией, и, тем более, называть таблицы и столбцы кириллицей.

```
// так НЕ НАДО называть:
`dlya_povara` (`Название блюда`, `Цена`, `Количество блюд`)
// условно, так НАДО называть:
`order` (`dish_name`, `price`, `dish_amount`)
// по-хорошему, все блюда надо хранить в отдельной таблице, в заказе указывать id блюда:
`order` (`dish_id`, `amount`)
```

2. В сам вопрос надо добавлять код, а не скриншоты.
3. Непосредственно, "решение" поставленной задачи.

```
function opt($array, $connect)
{
    if ( is_array($array) ) {

        // инициируем переменную, в которую будет записываться весь запрос 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `dishes` (`dish_name`, `price`, `dish_amount`) VALUES ";

        foreach ($array as $row => $value) {

            // берём item_name с массива
            $item_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $value['item_name']);
            // берём item_price с массива
            $item_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $value['item_price']);
            // берём item_quantity с массива
            $item_qty = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $value['item_quantity']);
            
            // "суффикс" к запросу, который добавляет запятую
            $suf = $row < count($array)-1 ? ", " : "";

            // не перезаписываем (=), а конкатенируем/прибавляем (.=) 
            // строку запроса + "суффикс" с запятой
            $sql .= "('$item_name','$item_price','$item_qty')" . $pre;
        }
          
        if ( mysqli_query($connect, $sql) ) {  
            echo '<script>alert("Регистрация прошла")</script>';  
        } else {
            echo '<script>alert("Регистрация не прошла")</script>';
        }
    }
}

opt($item_array, $connect);
```